# Is banning crusade costumes in Qatar denying freedom of expression?

Tags: freedom-of-speech, human-rights

- [Crusaders banned in qatar](https://youtu.be/a52liOOuxpI)

English fans with crusader costumes were banned in Qatar.

Is this a violation of freedom of speech/expression and, consequently, a violation of basic human rights of [Article 10 of the European Convention on Human Rights](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_10_of_the_European_Convention_on_Human_Rights) (ECHR?)

Explain why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Sure, but Qatar is not in the jurisdiction of the ECHR!

For the ECHR to apply in a jurisdiction, Qatar would need to have signed it or be in the EU or at least have been in it. It never has been. In fact, not even Den Haque would have power over Qatar unless they allowed it to - and that court rules on matters of war crimes...

Qatar does **not** guarantee the same rights you might be familiar with from most western countries. In fact, not even all western countries are the same. [In America, you can use the Sieg Heil gesture](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/53550/what-is-the-shortest-illegal-statement/53552?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C19.3978#53552), [in Germany, you can end in jail for it.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/78348/why-do-some-laws-make-saying-heil-hitler-illegal-when-other-laws-allow-freedom/78349?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C15.7466#78349). [Same for Propaganda materials](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/78391/is-it-allowed-to-share-propaganda-materials-for-educational-purposes-materials/78438?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C18.1489#78438).

Answer (score 5):

First Article 10 is a European thing and Qatar is not in Europe. And lots of places restrict freedom of expression.

Try a nazi uniform in Germany or, before Brexit, publicizing that you sympathize with the goals of a terrorist group in the UK.

Comment: What's Brexit got to do with ECHR / HRA1998?

Comment: UK is no longer in Europe and I was commenting on free speech restrictions in places under Article 10. Sorry it wasn’t clear.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite - The UK is no longer in the EU, but ECHR is a Council of Europe (and not an EU) thing. The UK is a member of the Council of Europe (and in respect of the comment, definitely still physically in Europe).

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate being corrected.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

However, not all restrictions on freedom of expression are violations of the law. Particularly not in an illiberal country like Qatar.

For example, even in a liberal democracy like Australia, my freedom of expression to express my dislike of someone does not allow me to defame them or punch them in the nose. I am also not allowed to wear a police or army uniform and pretend to be a police or army officer.  I also can’t indulge my love of death metal by playing it as loud as I want at 2am in a residential area.

What is allowed in Qatar is a matter for Qatari law. I have no idea what Article 10 you are referring to (because that article of the Universal Declaration of Human Rights has nothing to do with free speech) but unless it is some part of Qatari law, it’s completely irrelevant.

Comment: It's Article 10, ECHR. See my edit to the OP

Comment: *Particularly not in an illiberal country like Qatar.* --- Define illiberal.

Comment: @user366312 illiberal = not liberal

Comment: @Rick when was Qatar admitted to the EU?

Comment: @DaleM - well, they seem to have bought their own members of the EU Parliament...

Comment: @JonCuster -> Politics SE.

Comment: But also note that "crusaders" have a very, very different meaning in muslim countries. Crusaders were evil westerners how came to rob and/or conquer muslim countries, killing lots of innocent people. Including lots of innocent Christians in Constantinople because they couldn't read the road signs. It would be like a bunch of Germans arriving in Nazi uniforms.

Comment: @gnasher729 How is that different from the way crusaders are understood in Christian countries. At least by people who have a high school level of medieval history.